# How do I stop applications fro asking to connect to dial up?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet-connection

I normally use ADSL to connect to Internet, but here dial-up is more reliable, so I need to have dial up connection when ADSL is down. How do I prevent programs form attempting to connect to Internet using dial up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Connections and select "Never dial a connection". Apply and you should be OK.